# Why am I receiving an error saving, wrong diskette message?

Tags: r, save

I recently updated R and R studio and when I tried to save a file, I received an error message that said:

Error saving (file name). The wrong diskette is in the drive. Insert %2 (Volume  Serial Number: %3) into drive %1.

This is the first time seeing this error message and don't know what to do. I cannot 'save as' either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reopen the file with encoding and then Save . I tried with UTF-8