# I am receiving an error saying wrong diskette in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I try to open R files in RStudio,  but I receive this error:
Error saving (file name). The wrong diskette is in the drive. Insert %2 (Volume Serial Number: %3) into drive %1.

Comment: What's the exact command you're running before getting that error?

Comment: I'm not running anything, it also happens when I try to save a R script, So I recieve the same error message but once it says error while opening the file and once error while saving the file

Comment: What operating system and R version are you running? Has it ever worked on your computer or is this a new install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I receiving an error saving, wrong diskette message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345260/why-am-i-receiving-an-error-saving-wrong-diskette-message)

Comment: I am using R version 4.2.2 on Windows 10, it has worked before but occasionally I get this error

Comment: Does this help? https://www.techinpost.com/the-wrong-diskette-is-in-the-drive/

Comment: @Miff, the linked question does seem to be the same issue. I'd be a little surprised if the answer there (change encodings when saving) was actually the solution given that the error seems to be something about storage device availability ...

Comment: A colleague of mine had the same problem today. She updated R studio before this happened. Can this be related to the update?